# jquery plugin pattern using jquery.data

Tags: jquery

I have seen this piece of code in jquery plugin patterns and the notes section mention that we could attach the plugin to the DOM element using the jQuery.data function. What I don't understand is how do I make use of this piece of code. Can somebody provide examples of how to use this functionality and explain its significance?

```
 $.fn[pluginName] = function (options) {
        return $Extend(this).each(function () {
            if (!$.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName)) {
                $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName,
                new Plugin( this, options ));
            }
        });
    };
```

Comment: See the docs [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)

Comment: I understand how .data works but I want to see how the above piece of code works within a jQuery plugin and what information is stored in the DOM by the above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the point of the code you provided specifically doesn't allow a plugin to be reinitialized.

What it's doing is that the first time you call the plugin on an element, it checks its `data` to see if a property, `'plugin_' + pluginName`, has already been set. If it has been, it does nothing further. If it hasn't been set, it calls the `new Plugin()` method and stores it in its `data`. That way, it is easily retrievable by the plugin methods. All the methods have to do is use `$(this).data('plugin_' + pluginName)` to retrieve anything about the plugin, specifically for that element.

So if you want to make 2 plugin calls, like:

```
$(".class").specialPlugin({
    key1: "value1"
});

$(".class2").specialPlugin({
    key23: "value23"
});
```

Then each element's data will only have information specifically to its original setup.

What's actually stored in the `data` is whatever `new Plugin` returns, and can range anywhere from a full object of many things or just the original `options` object, for easy reference.